# Javascript - Update deep complex object in a generic way

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

### INTRODUCTION

I have the following javascript map (new Map()):

```
// Note: I am displaying my map like an object (for simplicity)

state = { 
  userId: {
    posts: [ // array
      { 
        id,
        isLiked,
        totalLikes,
        comments: { // object
          commentId: { isLiked, totalLikes, totalComments },

          ... more comments ...

        },
      },

      ... more posts ...

    ],
  }
}
```

And I am implementing a method "like" with the following form:

```
function like(state, contentOwnerId, contentType, contentId, commentId = undefined) {}
```

which will be useful for liking a user post, or a comment (inside a user post)

Basically, if I pass the map I described before as argument when calling it, the method will have to return me the same "state" map, but with the "isLiked" and "totalLikes" of the target post or comment **alterned**.

### CURRENT CODE

This is my current implementation:

```
function like(state, contentOwnerId, contentType, contentId, commentId = undefined) {
  const prevUserState = state.get(contentOwnerId);
  const prevContents = prevUserState[contentType];

  // Get the target content (or comment)
  let targetContent = prevContents.find((content) => content.id === contentId);

  if (commentId) {
    targetContent = targetContent.comments[commentId];
  }

  // Toggle the like
  const isLiked = !targetContent.isLiked;

  // Calculate the new totalLikes
  const totalLikes = targetContent.totalLikes + (isLiked ? 1 : -1);

  return new Map([
    ...state,
    [
      contentOwnerId,
      {
        ...prevUserState,

        // HOW CAN I UPDATE THE REST?
      },
    ],
  ]);
}
```

### PROBLEM

It is not finished yet, I don't know how to return the data correctly.

### UPDATE!

After all, I have decided to split my logic inside helpers. But, the code is not really optimized :(

```js
function like(state, contentOwnerId, contentType, contentId, commentId) {
  const prevUserState = state.get(contentOwnerId);
  const prevContents = prevUserState[contentType];
  const targetContent = prevContents.find(content => content.id === contentId);

  if (!commentId) {
    likeContent(targetContent);
  } else {
    likeContentComment(targetContent, commentId);
  }
  
  const newContents = prevContents.map(content => content.id !== targetContent.id ? content : targetContent )

  return new Map([
    ...state,
    [
      contentOwnerId,
      {
        ...prevUserState,
        [contentType]: newContents,
      },
    ],
  ]);
}


/*
  HELPERS
*/

function likeContent(content) {
  // Toggle the like
  content.isLiked = !content.isLiked;

  
  // Calculate the new totalLikes
  content.totalLikes = content.totalLikes + (content.isLiked ? 1 : -1);
}

function likeContentComment(content, commentId) {
  // Toggle the like
  content.comments[commentId].isLiked = !content.comments[commentId].isLiked;



  // Calculate the new totalLikes
  content.comments[commentId].totalLikes =
    content.comments[commentId].totalLikes +
    (content.comments[commentId].isLiked ? 1 : -1);
}


/*
   TESTS
*/

const state = new Map([]);
const userId = "alex";
const userPosts = [
   {
     id: "92uwdq092",
     isLiked: true,
     totalLikes: 10,
     comments: {
        "aiosxjoiao": { isLiked: false, totalLikes: 9, totalComments: 3 },
        "0ffSiSUi2P": { isLiked: false, totalLikes: 0, totalComments: 2 },
     }
   },
   {
     id: "78q78w0w0",
     isLiked: false,
     totalLikes: 0,
     // No comments!
   },
];

state.set(userId, { posts: userPosts });



// ----- First call ------
const newState1 = like(state, "alex", "posts", "78q78w0w0");

console.log(JSON.stringify(newState1.get("alex").posts, null, 2));


// ----- Second call -----
const newState2 = like(state, "alex", "posts", "92uwdq092", "0ffSiSUi2P");

console.log(newState2.get("alex").posts);
```

### INPUT

```
const state = new Map([]);
const userId = "alex";
const userPosts = [
   {
     id: "92uwdq092",
     isLiked: true,
     totalLikes: 10,
     comments: {
        "aiosxjoiao": { isLiked: false, totalLikes: 9, totalComments: 3 },
        "0ffSiSUi2P": { isLiked: false, totalLikes: 0, totalComments: 2 },
     }
   },
   {
     id: "78q78w0w0",
     isLiked: false,
     totalLikes: 0,
     // No comments!
   },
];

state.set(userId, { posts: userPosts });


// ----- First call ------
const newState1 = like(state, "alex", "posts", "78q78w0w0");

// ----- Second call -----
const newState2 = like(state, "alex", "posts", "92uwdq092", "0ffSiSUi2P");
```

### OUTPUT 1

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(newState1.get("alex").posts, null, 2));
/*
   [
      {
        id: "92uwdq092",
        isLiked: true,
        totalLikes: 10,
        comments: {
           "aiosxjoiao": { isLiked: false, totalLikes: 9, totalComments: 3 },
           "0ffSiSUi2P": { isLiked: false, totalLikes: 0, totalComments: 2 },
        }
      },
      {
        id: "78q78w0w0",
        isLiked: true,
        totalLikes: 1,
      },
   ]
*/
```

### OUTPUT 2

```
console.log(newState2.get("alex").posts["92uwdq092"].comments["0ffSiSUi2P"].isLiked);
/*
   true
*/

console.log(newState2.get("alex").posts["92uwdq092"].comments["0ffSiSUi2P"].totalLikes);
/*
   3
*/
```

Comment: 1. Is there a specific reason you're using a Map here instead of an object? 2. Is there a reason it has to be a new Map every time it's updated?

Comment: @rayhatfield 1. No reason, I just decided to use it looking for the future, in order to avoid refactorings because of the possible need of "iterability-in-order". 2. The new map is because I am using Reactive Programming, to cause UI re-renders.